# Secure Http Post

Tags: security, encryption, webserver, https

I am creating a software for PC that will periodically validate the license in the server (VPS) thought http post. Basically it will send a string to the server containing user id, license id, computer id, etc., and server will reply with another string, validating (or not) the license. I am not an expert in this subject, so have some questions:

1. Some "man in the middle" could intercept this communication and change sensitive data (in both way), correct?
2. Using HTTPS alone would be good solution for man in the middle attack? Or should I (also) use AES-256 for encrypt strings?
3. Using HTTPS (w/o AES encryption), can a "hacker" duplicate the post multiple times for doing a DoS (Denial of Service) attack?
4. About question 3 (DoS attack), my idea for solution is to use a token validation with expire time. Is this a good approach?
5. About question 4 (token), every time a license validation occours it will generate 2 posts to the server, first one to get the token and second one to send data. Am I Correct? Is there another way to get the same result with only one post?

Any tips about this subject will be very welcome! Btw, my software will coust about 40 usd, so I do not think a super hyper security is needed... Thanks!!

Comment: Please @Ramhound and DavidPostill could you explain why do you think it's a opinion-based question? I am asking for facts, not opinions!

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**: I'm not an expert regarding secure exchanges... even if i know a bit. For a lot of experts, i advice you post your question to [security dedicated stack](https://security.stackexchange.com)

> Some "man in the middle" could intercept this communication and change sensitive data (in both way), correct?

Using only HTTP: **yep**.

Using HTTPS: if you do not embed your own certificate authority to validate your server's certificate directly on your application, then **yep too** cause one can easily make a fake licence server with an HTTPS certificate signed with a fake certificate authority previously added to his "trusted certificate store".

> Using HTTPS alone would be good solution for man in the middle attack? Or should I (also) use AES-256 for encrypt strings?

To strictly secure the transport, you can trust HTTPS.... if you had correctly implemented the HTTPS certificate check.

> Using HTTPS (w/o AES encryption), can a "hacker" duplicate the post multiple times for doing a DoS (Denial of Service) attack?

Not sure that duplication of previous session will be enought to create a valid HTTPS session on server side.
Any way, polluting server with that kind of inconsistent traffic may lead to a DoS too..

> About question 3 (DoS attack), my idea for solution is to use a token validation with expire time. Is this a good approach?

DoS are DoS because the server is busy doing something else. 
Your token may protect you against replay attack, but won't protect your server against huge amount of useless traffic since it will always have to compute it to validate token.

> About question 4 (token), every time a license validation occours it will generate 2 posts to the server, first one to get the token and second one to send data. Am I Correct? Is there another way to get the same result with only one post?

There's several approaches to implement this.
One i used in the past was using a `nonce` (random value) and a `timestamp` as part of the request:

- Client push `nonceA` and `tsA` + its identifiers.
- Server checks that `tsA` is +/- `now()` (let's accept a 3 seconds delay) and push `nonceA` + `tsB` + the rights granted to the client.
- Client verify that `nonceA` is correct and `tsB` is +/- `now()`

This should protect you against replay attack.
You could obfuscate the protocol used over HTTPS using a ciphered payload.
For example, client could request server with the following JSON payload:

```
    "identifier": "it's identifier",
    "machine_id": "it's machine id",
    "payload"   : "AES_variant_of_your_choice(IV=part of identifier, KEY=machine_id, CLEAR_TEXT=nonceA+tsA+others identifier)"
```

Take care while choosing your AES variant cause misused, some can leak information and/or allow modification of information.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I now have a better understanding of the process! About the 5th question, client computer does not always have the same time (and date) as the server, but anyway it will not prevent DoS attack... My idea now is to use only AES-256 to encrypt the strings, and generate the token in software (client), so it will accept server reply only with same token (only one post).

Comment: @Guybrush - For secure encryption to work it needs to have the same time and date.

Comment: For your token to work, you have to make sure that no one can generate one... this is not THAT easy. Usually, you need to have a common secret, or use an asymetric algorithm ...